# Cant load xib from bundle

Tags: objective-c, xib, nib

The view i try to load is always nil! I tried project clean, restarting Xcode, renaming and recreating xib but no luck. What problem can it be?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you set **owner** in Interface Builder? Then change your code as @user3593377 suggested.

Comment: tried this as well and no good

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
CSDAlertView *aView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CSDAlert" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
NSArray *CSDAlertNib = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CSDAlert" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
CSDAlertView *aView = CSDAlertNib[0];
aView.frame = frame;
return aView;
```

as the return type is NSArray.